# How to find the RMS value of an arbitrary wave form in python

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I would like to calculate the RMS value of any waveform using its amplitude and time vectors.
for example:

```
Amplitude =1000*np.array([0,0,0,0.00000121,0.00000113,0.00000104,7.00E-07,1.06E-22,1.06E-22,1.06E-22,1.06E-22,-1.06E-22,-5.00E-07,-1.06E-22,0.00000187,5.50E-07,-2.12E-22,-2.12E-22,-2.12E-22,-4.76E-22])
time = np.array([0,0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08,0.1,0.12,0.14,0.16,0.18,0.2,0.2,0.45,0.45,0.47,0.49,0.51,0.53,0.55,1.5])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute RMS, you need to compute the integral of square of the Amplitude w.r.t time. This can be done with [`numpy.trapz`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html) From the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) of RMS, you can compute RMS as

```
RMS = np.sqrt(np.trapz(Amplitude**2,time)/(time[-1]-time[0]))
```